git apply 3 way merge and resume/continue
I have a patch file generated via git format-patch HEAD^1
Git apply keeps failing so I did a 3 way merge using git apply -3 patchfile
This worked fine, one file ended as U. I manually resolved the conflict.
What is the right action after this?
Say I want the patch to carry the same metadata like author/date etc, how do I do this? There is no such thing as git am --continue etc that works here.
When we rebase, we have that option during interactive rebase.
I can just proceed via doing git add of the file that I resolved the merge conflict and do a git commit. Is this the only way in such a situation?

To my understanding, the commands that take --continue can deal with more than one object (like commits and mail messages) in a single call. --continue ends the current conflicted object and continues to process the next.

git apply does not preserve metadata. You should have used git am -3 patchfile.
